# problem with dash character between page numbers in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I write the following LaTeX code to get the bibliography but the output is having problem with page number format.

```
\bibitem{Nicanfar}
H. Nicanfar, P. Jokar, and V. Leung, ``Smart grid authentication
and key management for unicast and multicast
communications,`` in IEEE PES Innovative Smart Grid
Technologies Asia (ISGT), pp. 1–8, 2011.
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Could anyone help me? I want the page number to appear as `pp. 1-8` not `pp. 18`.

Comment: You need to replace the non-ASCII character `–` with `-` ("dash").

Comment: Might be a little bit off-topic but I would like to point out that using only numbers for referencing bibliography entries is often a bad decision. There are a lot of standards for this and I suggest that you use a more descriptive referencing style (first author's name + year for example).

Comment: Also the long hyphen is usually done by `--` (two consecutive ASCII hyphens).

Answer (score 2):

You currently have a non-ASCII character -- `–` -- in the string `pp. 1–8`. You should either replace it with `--` (2 consecutive dashes, which will be typeset as an en-dash) or enable `utf8` input encoding along with setting up a font that knows what to do with `–`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % enable utf8-encoded characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Nicanfar}
H. Nicanfar, P. Jokar, and V. Leung, ``Smart grid authentication
and key management for unicast and multicast
communications,`` in IEEE PES Innovative Smart Grid
Technologies Asia (ISGT), pp. 1–8, 2011.  % <-- non-ASCII dash

\bibitem{Nicanfar}
H. Nicanfar, P. Jokar, and V. Leung, ``Smart grid authentication
and key management for unicast and multicast
communications,`` in IEEE PES Innovative Smart Grid
Technologies Asia (ISGT), pp. 1--8, 2011. % <-- 2 plain dashes

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```